# Can't make any module work with PNotify (Angular)

Tags: angular, pnotify

Using "modules" with **PNotify 4** doesn't work at all.

I'm using PNotify with Angular 6. I'm following PNotify's instructions in order to make the notifications look and behave like they should on mobile. PNotify should even be ready for mobile straight out of the box, but not on my code for some reason.

```
PNotify.notice({
    title: 'Mobile features',
    text: 'Trying to enable mobile module',
    modules: {
        Mobile: {
            swipeDismiss: true,
            styling: true
        }
    }
});
```

**Expected result:**
The notifications look "good" on mobile (100% in width). Notifications are swipe-able.

**Actual result:**
The notifications look like on desktop and aren't swipe-able.

Comment: As you said it should work on mobile by default, so you even are not obliged to specify **Mobile** module. PNotify 4 still is under development, so maybe it's the problem with lib itself.